# How to translate 'ago' in interval time formatter in views?

Tags: views, 8

Googling the only thing I've managed to find is: https://www.drupal.org/node/2800563

What can I do to translate 'ago' or omit it from printing?

Answer (score 0):

can't we do like this?

```
  //Get today's date.
  $today = getdate();
  //Calculate the date "1 week ago".
  $start_time = mktime(0, 0, 0,$today['mon'],($today['mday'] - 7), $today['year']);
```

Also, you can change those zeroes to make 'n' hours/ minutes/ seconds ago.

Comment: I was asking about how to translate the string that follows the time format, not how to convert dates.

I apologize if my question was not clear enough for you.